# Use MLPClassifier Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I try to use the MLPClassifier from github:

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py

But I actually don't see how I can use it with my own data. I have a feature matrix X of dimension 20000x100 and a target vector y with 5 classes of size 20000.

X and y are saved in a numpy array. What I'm confused about is the following:

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input]) #n_input is 100 here, right?
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])


total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size) #What is that for my data?


batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)#what are these?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your variable `batch_x` you will see it's simply a numpy array of shape `[batch_size, 784]`, so `batch_size` flattened images and `batch_y` is an array of shape `[batch_size, 10]`, so 1 one-hot encoded label per image in `batch_x`

So if you want to use your own data with this model, you have to :

- either have your data formatted in the same way (`[batch_size, 784]` and `[batch_size, 10]`)
- or change your placeholders `x` and `y` so that they can take in the shape of your own data

In your case then simply change the code indeed using:

```
n_input = 100
n_classes = 5
total_batch = int(20000/batch_size)
```

Also it is a better practice not to use numbers as above, rather get these values from your data :

```
n_input = your_x_data.shape[1]
n_classes = your_y_data.shape[1]
# or n_classes = your_y_data.max(axis=1) 
# if your y data array is not already one-hot encoded
total_batch = int(your_x_data.shape[0]/batch_size)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still have problem with my y. When I define y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes]) with n_classes=5, then my y has dimension ?x5 and not ?x1? Also I am not sure about total_batch? I think thats just one in my case, right?

Comment: I solved the problem with y, it is represented as a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @ted, you will have to modify the calculation of `total_batch`.
`total_batch` is the number of batches that your network will generate. You will have to replace `int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)` by `int(20000/batch_size)` or `int(X.shape[0]/batch_size)`, assuming that X contains your data. You can choose a batch size there, for example 200.

Comment: What exactly is batch_size in my example? From my understanding it should be one feature, right? So it should be equal one?

Comment: The batch size is the number of events processed by the neural network before performing a parameter update. If you choose a higher batch size, the training will be less prone to fluctuations in your data set, but may converge a bit more slowly. You may want to have a look at http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/, especially the section about the gradient descent variants. There you will find a good explanation of what a mini-batch is.